# Math.random()  и MAX_VALUE

Tags: actionscript

Хотелось бы узнать в каком диапазоне числа в Math.random().

И какому числу равно MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.random() - от 0.0 до 1.0 (не целые)

MIN_VALUE / MAX_VALUE для разных типов разное:

int - -2,147,483,648 (-2^31) до 2,147,483,647 (2^31-1).

Number - 2.225e-308 до 1.79e+308. (double-precision IEEE-754)

uint - 0 до 4,294,967,295 (2^32-1).